# warnings after upgrading to ruby 2.2.0

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
/gems/htmlentities-4.3.2/lib/htmlentities/mappings/expanded.rb:465: warning: duplicated key at line 466 ignored: "inodot"

/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/fog-core-1.25.0/lib/fog/core/collection.rb:144: warning: circular argument reference - filters
```

The obvious suspicion is that these gems don't like ruby 2.2.0, but things seem to be working

Should I fear future, imminent failures, or has these gems just haven't caught up yet?

Comment: I assume you tried upgrading the gems?

Comment: They are dependencies of other gems, so these are the latest which match

Comment: fog/fog fixed the warning https://github.com/fog/fog/pull/3370, fog-core I did not find.

Answer (score 10):

Both problems were solved in newer versions of these gems.

If I am depending on gems like that, I usually wait a little bit before switching the project to the latest and greatest ruby in production. Gems need time to get compatible with all the changes.

Answer (score 2):

I to have like this error when install redmine 3.2:
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/htmlentities-4.3.1/lib/htmlentities/mappings/expanded.rb:465: warning: key "inodot" is duplicated and overwritten on line 466

> All is simple - just edit this file and remove duplicated line!)

But sometimes need just check your htmlentities version and remove not needed

> ```
> gem list htmlentities
> gem uninstall htmlentities -v '4.x.x'
> ```

Answer (score 1):

My System Config: Win 8.1 + SQL 2016 Expr SP1 + Redmine DB (type SQL 2012 CS AI) + Redmine 3.3.1 + Ruby 2.3.3 + devkit + ImageMagick-6.9.6-8-Q16-HDRI-x64-dll (ImageMagick-7.0.3 Not working!)

Fix issue with htmlentities-4.3.1 "key inodot"

```
gem install htmlentities -v '4.3.4'
gem uninstall htmlentities -v '4.3.1'
```

Fix issue with error load "tiny_tds"

```
gem install tiny_tds -v '1.0.5'
gem uninstall tiny_tds -v '0.6.2'
```

Change all dependencies in Gemfile & Gemfile.lock from old version to new installed.

All other commands from Installing Redmine Guide Site.

Result:

```
c:\inetpub\redmine>bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

```
migrating
add_column(:roles, :settings, :text)
-> 0.0019s
-> -1 rows
AddRolesSettings: migrated (0.0027s)
```

```
c:\inetpub\redmine>set REDMINE_LANG=ru
c:\inetpub\redmine>bundle exec rake redmine:load_default_data
```

Default configuration data loaded.

```
c:\inetpub\redmine>bundle exec rails server webrick -e production

=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.7.1 application starting in production on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2016-12-13 15:14:25] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2016-12-13 15:14:25] INFO  ruby 2.3.3 (2016-11-21) [x64-mingw32]
[2016-12-13 15:14:25] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=4468 port=3000
[2016-12-13 16:02:58] INFO  going to shutdown ...
[2016-12-13 16:02:58] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
Exiting`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 gem uninstall htmlentities -v '4.3.2'
 gem install htmlentities -v '4.3.4'
```